# find image height when before loaded image

Tags: javascript

i have one problem. now i dynamically create a div for displaying images based on image width and height. so how can i find image's width and height before loading images or using image src? help plz

Comment: My suggestion would be style the image so its `visibility:hidden` (maybe even off screen somewhere) get the dimensions you want from it, then put the image where you need/want it on the page and set it to `visibility:visble`

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in Firefox that if an img is not absolute postion, the parent div of the img is already stretched to the size of the unloaded embedded img, like when you see the alt text (if set). Maybe if you appended an img to a div with no padding for just a nanosecond, retrieve the height of the div and then remove the div.

Comment: Browser can't know the size of an image *before* loading it. How could it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cant know the size of an image before you load it ... (*it makes sense really*)

Comment: +1 Of course it makes sense, I don't understand why people upvote other answers instead of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not make it just with javascript. You need some server side script to make it possible. Can you explain your purpose for getting width and height? Actually, you can change the width and height after image loading.

Comment: please see this url:http://www.prohive.com/portfolio?pid=10.

Comment: @Jeny, a quick IE inspector debug demonstrates that the problem is a disable() function is missed in javascript. Can you tell me where you have written the function and I can review it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a server script that serves your images and change it so that it returns image size if certain parameter is passed to it. Then use ajax to call it before you load an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image on your page (hidden), then inspect the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties, but I don't think this works in all browsers (I know it works in Firefox)

However [it looks like this person](http://arunprasad.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-for-image-element-in-internet-explorer/) figured out a way to use an `*.htc` file and IE's `behavior` rules to obtain the naturalWidth/naturalHeight in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to do something like this, I display it with position: absolute; left: -10000px; Then I can inspect the height and width, create the div and detach / attach it to the proper place.